# Saving decimal and currency in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, currency

Is it possible to save numbers with grouping separators and currency into core data and if so can someone point me in the right direction.

I have mile.text which is a decimal number with the grouping separator, payPerMile.text which is currency and then the grossPay.text which is also currency.

Everything calculates and displays fine until I save it. I print the numbers when I save, everything after the grouping separator is gone and the currency lines display as NaN.

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let item = item {

        item.startdate = startDate.text
        item.unitnumber = unitNumber.text
        item.miles = NSDecimalNumber(string: miles.text ?? "0.0")
        item.paypermile = NSDecimalNumber(string: payPerMile.text ?? "0.00")
        item.grosspay = NSDecimalNumber(string: grossPay.text ?? "0.00")
        item.company = company.text
        item.destination = destination.text
        item.enddate = endDate.text

    } else if let entitydescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DriveAwayMain", in: pc) {

        let item = DriveAwayMain(entity: entitydescription, insertInto: pc)

        item.startdate = startDate.text
        item.unitnumber = unitNumber.text
        item.miles = NSDecimalNumber(string: miles.text ?? "0.0")
        item.paypermile = NSDecimalNumber(string: payPerMile.text ?? "0.00")
        item.grosspay = NSDecimalNumber(string: grossPay.text ?? "0.00")
        item.company = company.text
        item.destination = destination.text
        item.enddate = endDate.text

    }
```

Comment: What is the schema of your Entity which is meant to have these currency values?

Comment: This might show just how far behind/little that I know. I have no clue what that means.

Comment: Do you have any good reason for needing to save the grouping separator at all? Is this a multi-currency app or what is your reason to include the currency when saving? Both of these can easily be added when reading and displaying the number.

Comment: I didn't think about having it display after the saved data is loaded... that would work. I changed the currency to decimal and got that to work but have no clue how to get the grouping separator to work.

Comment: @OEZ Did you see my answer? It shows you how to do this. You use the number formatter to convert the entered string into a number. You store the number. Then you can use the number formatter to convert the number back into a string for display to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber(string:)` only accepts plain numbers, not formatted numbers. If the user is entering formatted currency values then you need to use a `NumberFormatter` in `.currency` mode to parse the string into a number.

Example:

```
print(NSDecimalNumber(string: "$4,560.45"))
```

Output:

> NaN

Using a `NumberFormatter`:

```
let curFmt = NumberFormatter()
curFmt.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
curFmt.numberStyle = .currency
if let num = curFmt.number(from: "$4,560.45") {
    print(num)
} else {
    print("Not valid currency number")
}
```

Output:

> 4560.45

Comment: I think I am in way over my head here..... I tried this last night and it didn't work but I think I know what I did wrong. When I get home I will try it again.

Comment: I got it to print but it still saves as NaN

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more details than just that statement.